# FQL links to objects

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

Okay, i had found two posts in facebook, with type 'link'.

1. https://www.facebook.com/zuck/posts/10101561824722531
2. https://www.facebook.com/georg.zubko/posts/1531938117018645

Then i trying to get likes to it

1. `SELECT object_id, object_type from like where object_id="10101561824722531"`

   It's return full lists of likes.
2. `SELECT object_id, object_type from like where object_id="10101561824722531"1531938117018645`

   It's return empty list of likes, but post on facebook has about 25 likes.

Is this bug? If no, What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I send this problem to facebook support, and they mark it as bag.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/851602208190874/